# When do I have to compile asp.net 4.0 project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-4.0

When server knows when to compile project ? If I change aspx file it detects changes and compile it on request ? What about changes in cs file ? Thanks for any help

Comment: changes in cs files need recompilation. Changes in aspx files don't..

Comment: @stian.net: Sometimes you need even only aspx files are changed, because those code in cs files can also be written in aspx files.

Comment: This depends on your desirable compilation process; for example, all of our code is pre-compiled, obfuscated and signed; even changes in *.aspx files require a recompilation/build. Also, to elaborate a little on what TheSmartest said, you may only change native web elements in *.aspx pages before they need to be recompiled too, things like adding a div, or some CSS; anything that runs on the server (`runat="server"`) will require recompilation in order for the new server elements to be recognised.

Comment: @The Smartest: You don't have to recompile if you change your aspx-files. Code in aspx-files is not compiled into dll. And you should not write c# code in your aspx-files anyway...

Answer (score 4):

Basically, it depends on your project type.

*Web Site* projects are compiled on the fly and any code modification in the site folder will trigger recompilation on execution.

*Web Application* projects need to be manually compiled (you'll see a *[your project assembly name].dll* in the bin folder).

Also, check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547590.aspx for more information about the difference between the 2 project types (and how they are compiled).

Comment: @bigb: Are you sure? I have VS 2010 and I can create Website Projects for .Net 4.0

Answer (score 1):

Using VS 2010 you may create `ASP.NET Web Application` or `ASP.NET MVC Application using` `.NET 2.0 - 4.0` of your choice.

The next details are applied for both `ASP.NET Web Application` and `ASP.NET MVC Application`:

`aspx` files most of the times contains only static HTML code and after you change it you don't need to recompile the whole project because server pickup your updated `aspx` file strait away. With `cs` files is different story, because in that case when you did any changes in `cs` file you need to compile it to produce new updated `dll` files which would contain your latest changes.

So if you did any changes in your `cs` files and did not recompile the project, your changes won't be available until you recompile the project.

Also using VS 2010 you may create `ASP.NET Web Site application`. In that case you don't need to recompile your project if you changing `cs` file. Your  source code will compiled automatically by ASP.NET on the server after first request.

More about Summary of Differences between `ASP.NET Web application` projects and `ASP.NET Web site projects` you may find here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547590.aspx

Answer (score 0):

With all the project types that exist in Visual Studio 2010 you have to recompile your code every time you make any changes in your .cs files.

In VS 2005 and 2008 there was a project type named "Web site", with this project type you did not have to recompile if you made changes in a code behind file.

For more information check out the differences between CodeFile and CodeBehind.

/Viktor

Comment: I have VS 2010 Ultimate here and I definitly still can create Website Projects (File -> New -> Website...). I also couldnt find any info on Google saying it was removed.

Comment: @atticae Here in comments people saying that it is still alive http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/29/vs-2010-web-deployment.aspx. So it is not removed. File -> New -> Website (easy)